# PrintPreview doesn't show print option

Tags: vba, excel, print-preview

I have developed a program in Excel VBA for my friend,

I have Excel 2013 on my laptop and everything is working fine. And I also checked it in the other PCs which has 2007 and 2010, everything worked fine.

There are a couple of userforms in my program and he can print from other two userform except from a particular userform.

When he click print button on the userform it takes him to the print preview as per my coding but there is no option to print in the print preview. He has Excel 2007.

Following is the code I have in all the userforms, only the sheet names are different.

This is not the only code, there are too many lines of codes. There are no errors in coding because it executed and shown print option in the print preview without errors on other PCs.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bills").PrintPreview
```

Any guesses why is this happening?

If there is any mistakes in coding then it shouldn't be working well on other PCs and if there is any problems on my friend's PC then print option shouldn't be shown in the PrintPreview when click print from all userforms.

Edit: 
This issue is really weird. I have three userform and all three does different things but at the end it shows print preview (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bills").PrintPreview) of the bill. When we click the print button on the userform it shows same sheet. From one userform it shows print preview with option to print. From the other two userform it shows print preview but there is no option to print. I have to close the main x (close) button to exit the preview. But these problems I have only on one PC on which it actually supposed to work. Please help.

[image]

Comment: This issue is really weird. I have three userform and all three does different things but at the end it shows print preview (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bills").PrintPreview) of the bill. When we click the print button on the userform it shows same sheet. From one userform it shows print preview with option to print. From the other two userform it shows print preview but there is no option to print. I have to close the main x (close) button to exit the preview. But these problems I have only on one PC on which it actually supposed to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this guy have using this code `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. Print preview working fine when you make it `True`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax should be

```
Worksheets("Bills").PrintPreview or ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
```

See example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193825.aspx)

Comment: Sorry,  it didn't work and I am in a big trouble. I used Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Bills").Printpreview False. I think this is similar to what you suggested.